# data-bind not displaying data in view page

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

This is how I have my page set up, but no data is being displayed, and I'm not sure why:

**JavaScript/knockout:**

```
 var getList = function () {
            Ajax.Get({
                Url: ...,
                DataToSubmit: {id: properties.Id },
                DataType: "json",
                OnSuccess: function (roleData, status, jqXHR) {
                    bindModel(roleData);

                }
            });
        };


    // Binds the main ViewModel
        var bindModel = function (data) {
            var _self = viewModel;

            ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $('#ListView')[0]);
        };

    var viewModel = {
            ListRoleTypes: ko.observableArray([]),
            .....
        };

 var roleViewModel = function (data) {
        var _self = this;
        _self.ContentRole = ko.observable(data.ContentRole);
        _self.RoleName = ko.observable(data.RoleName);
        _self.RoleRank = ko.observable(data.RoleRank);
        _self.UserCount = ko.observable(data.UserCount);
    };
```

**This is my View page:**

```
<div data-bind="foreach: ListRoleTypes">
            <span data-bind="text: RoleName"></span>
        </div>
```

Any thoughts on where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are calling bindmodel and passing in the roledata, but then in bindmodel, you dont do anything with it.

```
Ajax.Get({
            Url: ...,
            DataToSubmit: {id: properties.Id },
            DataType: "json",
            OnSuccess: function (roleData, status, jqXHR) {
                bindModel(roleData);

            }
        });
    };


// Binds the main ViewModel
    var bindModel = function (data) {
        // need to do something with viewmodel to handle the passed in data
        viewmodel.initialize(data);

        ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $('#ListView')[0]);
    };
```

Comment: great - i got it going and now i added another model so i have data from two different models and i would like to create a foreach loop in which i will have an outer loop (listRoleTypes) and the inner loop will be users so that i will list users for each list role type